# Update the value of Ember TextField using jQuery.val()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

i have these lines in my view:

```
 //this code is within a {{#each item in controller.content}} so id will not be unique
 //so by giving it just an id like i have is not going to work 
 {{#each item in controller.content}}
   <div class="pull-right" id="qnty-bulk">{{view Ember.TextField class="span1 qnty-bulk" id="qnty-bulk" valueBinding="item.qnty" type="number" min="1" max="9999999" disabled=true}}</div>
   <button class="pull-right" {{ action "increase" }}>
       Up
   </button>
 {{/each}}
```

In my controller i have in the actions

```
 actions: {
    increase: function() {
        var inputField = $("#qnty-bulk");  //how can I access the Ember.TextField here for each of my items in the {{#each item in controller.content}}??
        var inputValue = inputField.val();
        inputValue = (inputValue != null && inputValue != '' ? (isNaN(inputValue) ? 0 : inputValue) : 0);
        inputValue++;
        console.log(inputField.val());
        inputField.val(inputValue);
    },
```

i want to increase the value of the textfield by 1 each time i click the up button
how can I do this?
can I use jquery?

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery. But I think you are missing the concept of data binding.

You made a value binding for the `TextField` using the `item.qnty` property.

Your increase function would look something like this:

```
actions: {
    increase: function() {
        var quantity = this.get('model.item.qnty');
        this.set('model.item.qnty', quantity++);
    },
}
```

You could even use a shortcut function:

```
actions: {
    increase: function() {
        this.increaseProperty('model.item.qnty');
    },
}
```

Ember will automatically detect that `item.qnty` has changed and update the value in the TextField.

You should never update your Ember values with by any other means than the Ember framework. Doing so could cause your Ember application to break, or is in this case, not work as expected.

**Edit, based on your comments.**

Your current hbs:

```
{{#each item in controller}}
    <div {{action increase}} ></div>
{{/each}}
```

This will trigger the `increase` function in your array controller, where as you want to edit an item in the array.

Lets specify an item controller for your items:

```
{{#each item in controller itemController='myItem'}}
    <div {{action increase}} ></div>
{{/each}}
```

Your MyItemController:

```
App.MyItemController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

    actions: {
        increase: function(){
            this.increaseProperty('model.qnty');
        }
    }
})
```

This will trigger the `increase` function in the item controller, where you have direct access to your item. It's always good to have an ArrayController for your arrays, and an ObjectController for your items in that array.

Comment: thanks but nothing shows in the textfield though and i get an error: Uncaught Error: Object in path model.item could not be found or was destroyed. ?

Comment: I'm wondering about your `item.qnty`. What is `item`?. You could try above code without the model prefixes.

Comment: item is: {{#each item in controller.content}} I am new to ember and trying to learn it on the fly. I have gone through the ToDo tutorial but dont understand everything yet, and this work must be done! :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use jQuery.

What you can do is pass the individual item in your content to the `increase` action and increase its value inside the action.

```
<div class="pull-right">
 {{input value=item.qnty type="number" min="1" max="9999999" disabled=true}}
</div>
<button class="pull-right" {{ action "increase" this}}>
 Up
</button>
```

And in your controller:

```
actions: {
increase: function(item) {
    var qnty = Ember.get(item,'qnty');
    Ember.set(item,'qnty',++qnty);
 }
}
```

A sample [Jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IDiKaQe/1/edit), for your use case.

Comment: You would be placing item logic in the array controller. This is a bad practice in my opinion.